# Errors Building GNUHAWK with REDHAWK 2.0

Tags: redhawksdr

Is it possible to build GNUHawk with REDHAWK 2.0? I understand that GNUHAWK is a rather old package but it would be very convenient.
I have successfully built Redhawk 2.0
I am using Boost 1.6
And I am running Centos 6.7

I have cloned the integration-gnuhawk repository and after installing the required dependencies and running ./reconf, ./configure, make it appears that the volk module of gnuradio builds properly. However when errors are encountered when trying to build the gnuhawk library.

First I get:

```
In file included from ../include/gnuhawk/gruel/msg_accepter.h:27,
             from ../include/gnuhawk/gr_msg_accepter.h:26,
             from ../include/gnuhawk/gr_basic_block.h:30,
             from gr_basic_block.cc:27:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:125: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Consumer_i’ with no type
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:125: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:140: error: ‘Consumer_i’ was not declared in this scope
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:140: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:140: error: template argument 4 is invalid
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:143: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘SupplierAdmin_i’ with no type
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:143: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
```

Then I see many messages similar to these

```
In file included from ../include/gnuhawk/gnuhawk.h:26,
             from ../include/gnuhawk/gr_msg_accepter.h:27,
             from ../include/gnuhawk/gr_basic_block.h:30,
             from gr_basic_block.cc:27:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:412: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_StringProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_StringProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
```

Here is the entire output of "make":

```
Making all in gnuradio/volk
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_cpu.h <- include/volk/volk_cpu.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk.h <- include/volk/volk_cpu.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk.h <- include/volk/volk.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_typedefs.h <- include/volk/volk_cpu.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_typedefs.h <- include/volk/volk.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_typedefs.h <- include/volk/volk_typedefs.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_config_fixed.h <- include/volk/volk_cpu.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_config_fixed.h <- include/volk/volk.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_config_fixed.h <- include/volk/volk_typedefs.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_config_fixed.h <- include/volk/volk_config_fixed.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_cpu.h <- include/volk/volk_cpu.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk.h <- include/volk/volk_cpu.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk.h <- include/volk/volk.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_typedefs.h <- include/volk/volk_cpu.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_typedefs.h <- include/volk/volk.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_typedefs.h <- include/volk/volk_typedefs.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_config_fixed.h <- include/volk/volk_cpu.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_config_fixed.h <- include/volk/volk.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_config_fixed.h <- include/volk/volk_typedefs.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Circular include/volk/volk_config_fixed.h <- include/volk/volk_config_fixed.h dependency dropped.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
[ 95%] Built target volk
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
[ 97%] Built target test_all
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
[100%] Built target volk_profile
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/gnuradio/volk'
Making all in include
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/include'
Making all in gnuhawk
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/include/gnuhawk'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/include/gnuhawk'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/include/gnuhawk'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/include/gnuhawk'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/include'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/include'
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/src'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"gnuhawk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"gnuhawk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.10.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"gnuhawk\ 1.10.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"gnuhawk\" -DVERSION=\"1.10.0\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_BOOST=1 -DHAVE_BOOST_THREAD=1 -DEXPECTED_VECTOR_IMPL=/\*\*/  -D__processor_unknown__ -D__linux__ -D__OSVERSION__=2 -DENABLE_EVENTS=1 -I/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include -I/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie -I/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/share/idl   -I../include/gnuhawk -I../include/gnuhawk/runtime -I../include/gnuhawk/gruel -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/filter -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/general -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gengen -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gruel -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/runtime -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio -I../gnuradio/volk/include -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/reed-solomon -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/hier -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/io -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/runtime -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/viterbi -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-atsc -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-audio -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-audio/alsa -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-digital -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-fcd -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-fft -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-filter -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-howto-write-a-block -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-noaa -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-pager -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-trellis -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-vocoder -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-wavelet  -UPACKAGE_NAME -UPACKAGE_BUGREPORT -UPACKAGE_TARNAME -UPACKAGE_STRING -UPACKAGE_VERSION  -pthread -I/usr/include -msse2  -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing  -MT gr_basic_block.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/gr_basic_block.Tpo -c -o gr_basic_block.lo gr_basic_block.cc
libtool: compile:  g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"gnuhawk\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"gnuhawk\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.10.0\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"gnuhawk 1.10.0\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"gnuhawk\" -DVERSION=\"1.10.0\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_BOOST=1 -DHAVE_BOOST_THREAD=1 "-DEXPECTED_VECTOR_IMPL=/**/" -D__processor_unknown__ -D__linux__ -D__OSVERSION__=2 -DENABLE_EVENTS=1 -I/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include -I/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie -I/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/share/idl -I../include/gnuhawk -I../include/gnuhawk/runtime -I../include/gnuhawk/gruel -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/filter -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/general -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gengen -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gruel -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/runtime -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio -I../gnuradio/volk/include -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/reed-solomon -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/hier -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/io -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/runtime -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/viterbi -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-atsc -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-audio -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-audio/alsa -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-digital -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-fcd -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-fft -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-filter -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-howto-write-a-block -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-noaa -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-pager -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-trellis -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-vocoder -I../include/gnuhawk/gnuradio/gr-wavelet -UPACKAGE_NAME -UPACKAGE_BUGREPORT -UPACKAGE_TARNAME -UPACKAGE_STRING -UPACKAGE_VERSION -pthread -I/usr/include -msse2 -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-strict-aliasing -MT gr_basic_block.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/gr_basic_block.Tpo -c gr_basic_block.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/gr_basic_block.o
In file included from ../include/gnuhawk/gruel/msg_accepter.h:27,
                 from ../include/gnuhawk/gr_msg_accepter.h:26,
                 from ../include/gnuhawk/gr_basic_block.h:30,
                 from gr_basic_block.cc:27:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:125: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Consumer_i’ with no type
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:125: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:140: error: ‘Consumer_i’ was not declared in this scope
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:140: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:140: error: template argument 4 is invalid
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:143: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘SupplierAdmin_i’ with no type
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/MessageInterface.h:143: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from ../include/gnuhawk/gnuhawk.h:26,
                 from ../include/gnuhawk/gr_msg_accepter.h:27,
                 from ../include/gnuhawk/gr_basic_block.h:30,
                 from gr_basic_block.cc:27:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:412: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_StringProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_StringProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(T&) [with T = bool]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:419: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_BooleanProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_BooleanProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(T&) [with T = char]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:426: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_CharProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_CharProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(T&) [with T = unsigned char]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:433: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_OctetProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:263: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_OctetProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(T&) [with T = short int]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:440: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_ShortProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:263: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_ShortProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(T&) [with T = short unsigned int]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:447: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_UShortProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:263: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_UShortProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(T&) [with T = int]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:454: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_LongProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:263: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_LongProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(T&) [with T = unsigned int]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:461: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_ULongProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:263: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_ULongProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(T&) [with T = float]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:468: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_FloatProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:263: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_FloatProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(T&) [with T = double]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:475: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_DoubleProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:263: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_DoubleProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:483: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_StringSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_StringSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = bool]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:490: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_BooleanSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_BooleanSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = char]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:497: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_CharSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_CharSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = unsigned char]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:504: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_OctetSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_OctetSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = short int]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:511: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_ShortSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_ShortSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = short unsigned int]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:518: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_UShortSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_UShortSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = int]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:525: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_LongSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_LongSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = unsigned int]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:532: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_ULongSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_ULongSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = long int]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:539: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_LongLongSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_LongLongSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = long unsigned int]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:546: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_ULongLongSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_ULongLongSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = float]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:553: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_FloatSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_FloatSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = double]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:560: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_DoubleSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_DoubleSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h: In static member function ‘static PropertyInterface* GR_PropertyWrapperFactory::Create(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&) [with T = std::complex<float>]’:
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:568: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘GR_ComplexFloatSeqProperty’
../include/gnuhawk/gr_properties.h:31: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘GR_ComplexFloatSeqProperty’:
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:84: note:  virtual void PropertyInterface::setValue(const CORBA::Any&, bool)
/home/wdjohns/redhawk/core/include/ossie/PropertyInterface.h:121: note:     virtual bool PropertyInterface::matchesAddress(const void*)
make[2]: *** [gr_basic_block.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/wdjohns/Downloads/integration-gnuhawk/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already answered the question. GNU Hawk includes a copy of GNU Radio 3.6.2, this was released in 2012. From a quick look at the messages, I suspect many of the compile errors are due to gcc becoming stricter every new release. All of these issues have been fixed in newer gnuradios.

Basically, someone needs to remove the old gnuradio from the gnuhawk source tree, and update gnuhawk to work with current gnuradio versions. That would lead to a supportable gnuhawk.